# Diff side by side output with "|" (incomplete) sign

Tags: command-line, output, diff

When I compare two files with just numbers, in addition to < and > signs, I also have | signs at some of the lines. For example,

> 25746                                                         | 26123

I checked the manual and it says

> ‘|’
>
> ```
> The corresponding lines differ, and they are either both complete or both incomplete.
> ```

This statement is not fully clear to me. I checked such lines and couldn't spot a difference than the others. How can I fix these lines to lines with < and >?

Thanks!

Comment: Relevant part of `info diff`: [Showing Differences Side by Side](https://www.gnu.org/software/diffutils/manual/diffutils.html#Side-by-Side). I was confused cause I couldn't find it in `man diff`.

Comment: Could you give an example command and a bit more output?

Comment: Did you read the example in `info diff`? [An Example of Side by Side Format](https://www.gnu.org/software/diffutils/manual/diffutils.html#Example-Side-by-Side)

Comment: Ok, with this example it makes more sense now. However, my goal is to count the different lines, i.e. with `<` and `>`. When I try to count the lines with `|` by using
`diff file1 file2 | grep "|"|wc -l` it returns `0`, but I have a lot of similar lines. Is there a way to include/change the lines with `|` into `<` and `>` so that I don't ignore them?

Comment: I also don't understand why it isn't like this

`25746 <` (next line)
`>26123` ?

Comment: Ok, I understand why it is '0'. When I say `diff file1 file2 | grep "<"|wc -l`, or `diff file1 file2 | grep ">"|wc -l`, those lines with `|` are counted separately for < and >. So, I can live with that. Thanks for the help.